# Why does inlining a function resolve type error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, event-handling

I'm currently encountering a type error when I pass a function directly an event handler

The function in question:

```
function handleScroll(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLElement>) {
  const scrollPosition = e.target.scrollTop;
  const scrollMax = e.target.scrollHeight / 1.25;
  const scrollPercentage = scrollPosition / scrollMax;

  const scaler = 1800;

  const bgPosition = (1 - scrollPercentage) * scaler - scaler / 2;

  scrollRef.current.style.transform = `translate(${bgPosition}px, 55%)`;
}
```

The event handler is on a div:

```
<div onScroll={handleScroll}>
```

This code will resulte with a type error `Type '(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLElement>) => void' is not assignable to type 'UIEventHandler<HTMLDivElement>'` on my `onScroll` event.

However, when I inline the function to be `<div onScroll={() => handleScroll}>` the type error is resolved.

In this context, why does inlining the function resolve the type error? Said a different way, why does the type `ChangeEvent<HTMLElement>` not match the event object?

Comment: Well `ChangeEvent<HTMLElement>` type is not the same as `UIEventHandler<HTMLDivElement>` type, the type of `e` should be updated to reflect the correct type, or you could type the function as a whole. Either to be: `e: React.UIEvent<HTMLDivElement>` or `const handleScroll: React.UIEventHandler<HTMLDivElement> = (e) => {}`

Comment: Here in the [TypeScript Github repo](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v5.1.6/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L8795) you can find the events and their types.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses.

Comment: The function `() => handleScroll` has type `() => (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLElement>) => void` which is a perfectly valid subtype of the expected event handler. It also doesn't do anything, it doesn't call the function or forward the arguments. If you want to actually call the function that you wrote, you'll need to declare an event parameter such that you can pass it along, and you will end up back where you started more or less